# Why won't DateTime format with "/"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime-format

I need to format a date into this specific format "1/23/2021" but for some reason it always returns as 1-23-2021 instead.

```
new DateTime().ToString("M/dd/yyyy")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The current culture uses `-` as its date delimiter. Use a string literal.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Noob question, How do I do that to convert format?

Comment: Yes it does thank you!

Comment: `DateTime.Now.ToString("M'/'dd'/'yyyy");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separators are *culture dependent*. Try providing *custom* separator. For current date it can be

```
 DateTime.Now.ToString("M'/'dd'/'yyyy")
```

For arbitrary `myDate` date

```
 myDate.ToString("M'/'dd'/'yyyy")
```